# Configure ELMAH to let certain errors through

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, elmah

I am working with a 3rd party ActiveX control which requests resources through a controller that I have developed. Without Elmah enabled a return code of 500 when a resource is not found tells the ActiveX control there has been an error. However, if a request fails and Elmah is catching and logging the error and redirecting the ActiveX control to the error page the ActiveX control is assuming the error page is the requested resource.

There is lots of information on the web regarding [filtering errors with Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFiltering) but I am unable to find any information on how to configure Elmah to leave some errors untouched and allow them to naturally propogate back to the client.

My current thoughts are that I will need 2 websites, one for the resource controller and another for everything else but before I go down this road does anyone have any suggestions for configuring Elmah to ignore certain routes and/or error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your problem, you gave the solution yourself, by providing a link to the filtering mechanism in ELMAH. Just dismiss the error if it's the one generated from the ActiveX control. This way ELMAH won't touch the error and your webserver will fail as normal.